# Norming features causes the allocated GPU space to grow

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the [OpenAI Clip Model](https://github.com/openai/CLIP) to calculate clip embeddings:

```
import torch
import clip
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request

model, preprocess = clip.load("ViT-B/32", device="cuda")
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Cat03.jpg", "cat")

def foo():
    with Image.open("cat") as img:
      image = preprocess(img).unsqueeze(0).to("cuda")
      image_features = model.encode_image(image)
      image_features /= image_features.norm(dim=-1, keepdim=True)

for _ in range(10):
  foo()
  print(torch.cuda.memory_allocated())
```

Output:

```
380955648
402444800
423933952
445423104
466912256
488401408
509890560
531379712
552868864
574358016
```

With each execution of `foo`, the allocated GPU space increases. I tried adding

```
del image
del image_features
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

at the end of `foo` but it only decreases the build up slightly.

The total allocated GPU memory still increases significantly with each execution of `foo`. This seems to be caused by `image_features /= image_features.norm(dim=-1, keepdim=True)`. Removing this line will result in no change of the allocated memory.

Since I need to calculate a lot of clip embeddings, this behavior eventually leads to the GPU filling up and the code crashing. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Try using `Image.open()` as a context manager, as in the first example [in the docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#examples).

Comment: Good catch! But the problem still remains

Comment: The problem is something I face very frequently. Your GPU will run out of space eventually while training such models especially when it has to do something with storing previous data such as during training with gradients. What I do that avoids blowing up the GPU memory is something like this:  Either add a `torch.no_grad()` and then add all your code within the indent, else just detach your model outputs and/or convert them to standard CPU values such as `model(params).to('cpu')`